# How to keep quotes in CSV-Files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, double-quotes, quoting

**Hello there,**

I have a problem with correct quotes when writing a CSV. I want to write a CSV file with the built-in Python-CSV-library. My code is the following:

```py
with open('test.csv', mode = 'w', newline = '') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',', escapechar = '"', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    csv_writer.writerow(['1', ' 0', ' Maker', ' "Tamas Nemes"'])
    csv_writer.writerow(['2', ' 0', ' Title', ' "A CSV file"'])
```

I tried many different parameter settings for the writer, but I always end up with this:

```
1, 0, Maker, ""Tamas Nemes""
2, 0, Title, ""A CSV file""
```

Is there a way to get it like this:

```
1, 0, Maker, "Tamas Nemes"
2, 0, Title, "A CSV file"
```

*Thanks for your help in advance!*

Comment: The existing output is *correct*. If you don't want quotes doubled to indicate that they're literal rather than syntactic, what you want isn't really CSV.

Comment: ...that said, if you want to convince the Python `csv.writer` to generate something that diverges in this way -- how about picking a completely different escape character (by modifying `escapechar`)? *That character* will be doubled when present in the input, or added before and after strings that contain commas, but quotes will be left alone. Or, of course, you could just not use `csv.writer`, insofar as you don't actually want the file format it's built to generate.

Comment: Why are you putting double quotes around `Tamas Nemes` if you don't want them to be put into the CSV file?

Comment: Use `csv_writer.writerow(['1', ' 0', ' Maker', ' Tamas Nemes'])` without the explicit double quotes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I want CSV because I'm trying to edit CSV files generated by fourmilab's MIDI-CSV program. In this kind of CSV, all properties of MIDI files are in seperate lines of the file. Some properties, such as Marker_t or Title_t need a string with quotes, for example: `0, 1, Marker_t, "(c) Tamas Nemes 2019"` This is why I want it to look exactly like that. Else the file gets corrupted and can't be re-converted to a MIDI again.

Comment: @Barmar when I use `csv_writer.writerow(['1', ' 0', ' Maker', ' Tamas Nemes'])`, Tamas Nemes doesn't get quoted at all. I want the output to look exactly as described or the file gets corrupted. In case the Python CSV-library isn't capable of solving this issue, I will have to modify the CSV manually.

Comment: Why do you need quotes around `Tamas Nemes`? Quotes are only needed if the field contains the field delimiter (comma) or line delimiter (newline). It seems like you have your own ideosyncratic format, like requiring a space after each comma. You shouldn't expect a standard formatter to create your specific data. It seems like you could just use `"".join(map(str, list))` to create each record.

Comment: @Totemi1324, just because MIDI-CSV calls something "CSV" doesn't mean it really *is* CSV. In this case, it's clearly not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to comment and I agree with @CharlesDuffy your kind of abusing the CSV format.

But you can get close to what you want by setting Escape Character to space (" ")

This will result in:

```
1,  0,  Maker, "Tamas  Nemes "
2,  0,  Title, "A  CSV  file "
```

Your strings are padded with extra spaces, but depending on what you need to do with them that might not matter.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to create isn't standard CSV format. You can simply join all the strings and write that.

```
with open('test.csv', mode = 'w', newline = '') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(",".join(['1', ' 0', ' Maker', ' "Tamas Nemes"']) + "\n")
    csv_file.write(",".join(['2', ' 0', ' Title', ' "A CSV file"']) + "\n")
```